# Replace all instances of a character between tags using Regexp or php functions

Tags: php, regex

All right, I'll be honest, I have only a vague Idea of what I'm talking about.
So I have this markup rule

```
$config['markup'][] = array("/\[tag\](.+?)\[\/tag\]/m", "<span style=\"font-weight:    bold\">$1</span>");
```

That formats the text in [tag][/tag]

How can I replace say, character x with character y, but only within [tag][/tag]?

I guess it can be done with php functions because there's this example code

```
// Highlight PHP code wrapped in <code> tags (PHP 5.3+)
// $config['markup'][] = array(
//  '/^&lt;code&gt;(.+)&lt;\/code&gt;/ms',
//  function($matches) {
//      return highlight_string(html_entity_decode($matches[1]), true);
//  }
// );
```

But I couldn't turn it into what I want. I'm not a programmer.

Comment: You could capture your character into a group then replace group 1: `(?<=\[tag\]).*?(d).*?(?=\[\/tag\])`.

Comment: Excuse my stupidity, is this the capture part? Then where does the character to be replaced go?

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking too complicated. All you need to do is:

```
$replaced_text=preg_replace("/\\[tag\\](.+?)\\[\\/tag\\]/m", "<span style=\"font-weight: bold\">$1</span>", $original_text);
```

Comment: So where do I place the character I want to replace? 
([x]+?) - 
like that?